# Use of ifdef in gas assembly language

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, binutils

I have following assembly  file mov.s

```
 .text
    .macro test_3
     and $3,%eax
    .endm

    movz:
    movzb   %al,%ax
     movzb   (%eax),%ax
     movzb   %al,%eax
        movzb   (%eax),%eax
    .ifdef test_3
        movzb33 %al,%rax
        movzb   (%rax),%rax
.endif
```

command `as -o dump.o movz`

In this code I want to test `ifdef` in assembly language so I have defined macro test_3.

According to my understanding it should print message 
`Error: no such instruction: 'movzb33 %al,%rax'` when I use assembler but it is not going inside `ifdef` so what is the problem?

Comment: Read the documentation of your particular assembler (is it [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) or [gas](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.28/as/index.html)?). `.ifdef` is a directive, not an instruction. Look into the generated object file (e.g. with `readelf` or `objdump` on Linux)

Comment: i know this thing

Comment: Bu did you carefully read the documentation (perhaps several times)?

Comment: use -a option to get listing

Comment: yes @Basile Starynkevitch I have to use symbol insted of macro thanks

Comment: @Sathiya: your edit had a mistake: you left out `as` from the code-formatting.  It's the name of the assembler command.  Thanks for making edits to help improve questions, but just wanted to point out what you missed so you can learn from the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`.ifdef` checks if a symbol is defined, it does not test macros. In GNU AS and many other assemblers macros can only be used where an instruction is permitted.

Comment: Also, if you *want* C preprocessor functionality, use CPP macros.  `gcc -c foo.S` will run it through CPP first, so you can use `#include` and `#ifdef`.